# Python Beautiful Soup table scrape

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I have been looking to scrape a HTML table from an oil production SSRS feed online. I have managed to learn a bit of beautiful soup/python to get to the point I am currently but I think I need a little assistance to just get it finished.

The aim is to scrape the table which is all  tagged and output json data. I have a json formatted output but for the 10 headers but it is repeating the same data row cell value per header. I think the iteration through the cells to assign to the headers is the issue. I'm sure it will make sense when run.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, trying to learn just what I have done wrong as this is pretty new to me.

Cheers

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import boto3
import botocore

#Url to scrape

url='http://factpages.npd.no/ReportServer?/FactPages/TableView/
    field_production_monthly&rs:Command=Render&rc:Toolbar=
    false&rc:Parameters=f&Top100=True&IpAddress=108.171.128.174&
    CultureCode=en'


#Agent detail to prevent scraping bot detection 
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5(Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) 
    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 
    Safari/537.36'

header = {'User-Agent': user_agent}

#Request url from list above, assign headers from criteria above
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = header)

#Open url from the previous request and assign
npddata = urllib.request.urlopen(req, timeout = 20)

#Start soup on url request data
soup = BeautifulSoup(npddata, 'html.parser')

# Scrape the html table variable from selected website 
table = soup.find('table')


headers = {}

col_headers = soup.findAll('tr')[3].findAll('td')

for i in range(len(col_headers)):
    headers[i] = col_headers[i].text.strip()

# print(json.dumps(headers, indent = 4))


cells = {}

rows = soup.findAll('td', {
    'class': ['a61cl', 'a65cr', 'a69cr', 'a73cr', 'a77cr', 'a81cr', 'a85cr', 
    'a89cr', 'a93cr', 'a97cr']})

for row in rows[i]: #remove index!(###ISSUE COULD BE HERE####)

# findall function was original try (replace getText with FindAll to try)

    cells = row.getText('div')


# Attempt to fix, can remove and go back to above
#for i in range(len(rows)): #cells[i] = rows[i].text.strip()


#print(cells)# print(json.dumps(cells, indent = 4))
#print(cells)# print(json.dumps(cells, indent = 4))


data = []

item = {}

for index in headers:
    item[headers[index]] = cells#[index]

# if no getText on line 47 then.text() here### ISSUE COULD BE HERE####

data.append(item)


#print(data)
print(json.dumps(data, indent = 4))
# print(item)# 
print(json.dumps(item, indent = 4))
```

Comment: Indentation is important in Python, please make sure your code samples have the correct indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some errors in your code i fix those errors and modified your code a little :

Is this what you want :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

# Webpage connection
html = "http://factpages.npd.no/ReportServer?/FactPages/TableView/field_production_monthly&rs:Command=Render&rc:Toolbar=false&rc:Parameters=f&Top100=True&IpAddress=108.171.128.174&CultureCode=en"
r=requests.get(html)
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")


rows = soup.findAll('td', {
    'class': ['a61cl', 'a65cr', 'a69cr', 'a73cr', 'a77cr', 'a81cr', 'a85cr',
    'a89cr', 'a93cr', 'a97cr']})

headers = soup.findAll('td', {
    'class': ['a20c','a24c', 'a28c', 'a32c', 'a36c', 'a40c', 'a44c', 'a48c',
    'a52c']})

headers_list = [item.getText('div') for item in headers]

rows_list=[item.getText('div') for item in rows]

final=[rows_list[item:item+9] for item in range(0,len(rows_list),9)]

row_header={}
for item in final:
    for indices in range(0,9):
        if headers_list[indices] not in row_header:
            row_header[headers_list[indices]]=[item[indices]]
        else:
            row_header[headers_list[indices]].append(item[indices])



result=json.dumps(row_header,indent=4)
print(result)
```

the sample of output:

```
{
    "Year": [
        "2009",
        "2009",
        "2009",
        "2009",
        "2009",
        "2009",
        "2010",
        "2010",
        "2010",
        "2010",
        "2010",
```

Comment: Awesome thanks very much @ayodhyankit Paul, I will have a study in a bit to see what you fixed, be good to learn from it.

Comment: Would there be an easy way to have a record per row? So for every row have one json record with the 10 headers in it, then next record would have the headers again for the 2nd row of scraped data?

Comment: @Chris you want those headers in each row  , can you show me example ?

Comment: Something like that if possible, not sure if it is simple to change: [{ "field" : alva, "year" : "2010", "month" : "3", "Oil" : "3233.", }, { "field" : alva, "year" : "2010", "month" : "3", "Oil" : "4556.", }]